# Using findAll two times BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping this webpage with some tables. I want to 'build' two lists and the site have the class 'txt' for two datatypes. I need to extract those datatypes separately, so I'm tryng to "filter" the first type, extract, and then doing the other type.

I made this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
page = soup.find('div', class_='content')
labels = page.findAll('td', class_='label')

Output: 
[<td class="label w15"><span class="help tips" title="Code">?</span><span class="txt">Paper</span></td>,
 <td class="label destaque w2"><span class="help tips" title="Last value">?</span><span class="txt">Value</span></td>]
```

I need what is inside those `<span class="txt">Paper</span>`

When I try this:

```
myfilter = labels.findAll('span', class_='txt')
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Why? How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't use a list of results as a result by itself. You need to loop over them.

```
myfilter = []
for label in labels:
    myfilter.extend(label.find_all('span', class_='txt'))
```

Comment: Hey, @Barmar. Thanks! I got a list with a bunch of itens <span class="txt">Paper</span>, <span class="txt">Value</span>. How can I get only the text "Paper", "Value"?

Comment: Use `.text` of the items in the list.

Comment: @Barmer : I believe you need to use `.append` instead of `.extend` in this case. `.extend` will duplicate the number of elements added to the empty list, whereas `.append` will add exactly the matched number of elements found via the `.find_all` call. Also, please note that `.findAll` is now deprecated and `.find_all` should be used in its place. I know I am commenting after more than a year's gap since your answer was posted, but thought it is worth mentioning here for the posterity's sake.

Comment: @Amar If you use `.append()` you'll get a list of lists instead of a single list.

Comment: @Barmer : That'd not be as big an issue as the duplication of number of elements added to the empty list if one uses the `.extend()` method

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by duplication of number of elements. It's not duplicating anything.

Comment: @Amar Do you mean that when a list is extended, it has to copy all the existing elements in the list to the new allocation? That also happens when you append. However, when python allocates lists, it leaves extra room for new elements. It only needs to reallocate when it exceeds this.

Comment: @Barmar You are right! My bad. Both times I cheked, I did not re-initialize the empty list, so that's why duplication occurred in my case. Sorry to bother you with trivial non-query.